# Habitat multisite solution structure example

Tags: helix, habitat

I've created my own helix based solution on the habitat project and I need to support multiple sites in this solution. But I don't know how to structure the Project folder here I need to create is the following basic structure the right approach or did I miss something?

- Project

  - Common
  - DotComWeb
  - DotComCommon
  - ShopsWeb
  - ShopsCommon

Comment: I hope you aren't using the habitat solution to start building out a new solution for your company, since it's not a starter kit.  If you are using it for learning purposes than this is fine and ignore me.

Comment: @DylanYoung No I've created my own complete new solution, I am just using the Gulp Task and Serialization setup from Habitat and the overall Structure but no projects and so on.

Comment: Maybe I'll get shamed, but we actually found `Sitecore.Foundation.Assets`, `Sitecore.Foundation.Dictionary`, `Sitecore.Foundation.FieldEditor`, `Sitecore.Foundation.LocalDatasource`, and `Sitecore.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions` to be rather helpful. TeamCity complains about C# coding standard issues which bumps up our issue counts, but otherwise these are pretty solid.

Comment: @JamesSkemp Yes I am also looking forward to this Modules to use them in the near future I hope this is ok :-)

Comment: Copy Habitat modules at your own risk. They are not supported by Sitecore. Better to incorporate and customize to your requirements.

Comment: @techphoria414 never complete modules just the code which looks like good and which I need to solve my problems :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I was setting up our project layer based upon [the Helix architecture principles for the project layer](https://helix.sitecore.net/principles/architecture-principles/layers.html#project-layer), this bit stood out to me:

> Typically, in a single tenant solution there will only be a single module, namely the specific website or requirements that fits the needs of the tenant, and this will contain little or no pre-compiled code but instead consist of mark-up, styling, layout and templates of the item types in Sitecore which the editors can create (see Template types).

And for Habitat:

> "The Common module paves the way for a multi-tenant implementation by defining some of the shared templates and settings between tenants."

So our current structure looks very similar:

- Project

  - AbcWebsite
  - Common
  - QrsWebsite
  - XyzWebsite

What I'm not sure is what the use case would be for another Common project for each website, as you've done.

Unless you have multiple multi-tenant implementations with their own shared code, I wouldn't expect you'd need another common project for each website. And if you do have multi-tenant implementations like that (such as if each multi-tenant instance is a different client/customer), I wonder if that should instead be a different Visual Studio solution, one for each client/multi-tenant instance.

This also means that if you don't have a multi-tenant solution, a Common project layer module wouldn't be required.

Comment: my above code was just an example what I thought it would look like :-)

Comment: :) Glad this helped!